# copy char* to std::string at the specified pos not allocating new objects

Tags: c++, string

Let me ask my question by code:

```
char* apples = "apples";
std::string str("I like .....");
// need to copy apples to str to have "I like apples", without creating new objects
```

There is [assign](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/) function but unfortunately it seems is not possible to provide `std::string offset`.

I do not want to allocate new object as this is low-latency and frequently part of code.

**upd** by mistake i've put 5 dots above but I meant 6 dots to fit "apples" perfectly :) Of course if string capacity is not enought some objects have to be created. In my question I assume that string capacity is enough.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Overwrite string's tail, like in my answer, or to append arbitrary string to your?

Comment: well i need overwrite "....". however append will also work. i can `resize` original string cutting `...` and then append...

Comment: Did you intend there to be six dots in the string, so that they could be overwritten with "apples" without resizing the string? As it is, the string will need to grow if you want to replace five dots with six letters.

Comment: @MikeSeymour 5 dots is not intentional. string may grow if capacity is not enough, but it will grow once and then i can reuse it many times, so this is ok. Moreover i call `reserve` before using so actually it should never grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`std::string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)?

Comment: if it works then the question is what is better `std::copy` or `std::string::replace`

Comment: @javapowered They don't do the same thing.

Comment: @javapowered: `replace` does (I think) what you want, replacing a substring with another string even if they have different lengths. `copy` will overwrite part of the string, and will go horribly wrong if the string isn't long enough (which is the case in your example).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes.  That's what I meant in another comment: `replace` is the safest solution.  And once the string has reached it's maximum capacity, there probably won't be any additional allocations.  (With CoW implementations, like g++, you might have to do something to "isolate" the implementation as well if you really must avoid all allocations.)

Comment: I'm afraid my answer is not what you are looking for, as replace does allocate a new string.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti That depends on the implementation, and the capacity of the string.  If he really needs absolute control over allocations, he needs `std::vector<char>`, with a combination of `resize` or `erase` (to get ride of the previously trailing characters) and `insert` to append the new ones.  I suspect, however, that with adequate precautions, he should be able to use `std::string::replace`, even if it is not guaranteed by the standard.  (In the case of g++, I'd have to look at the implementation to be sure.)

Comment: @NicolaMusatti why `replace` allocate a new string? why the same string can not be reused?

Comment: @javapowered It's just not in stardard. Standard just states, that replace must be sure that string can hold your string. It can just copy, or reuse, or anything else...

Comment: @kassak well i hope that if string capacity is enough all major compilers will just use existent buffer. why someone need to allocate new object when existent can be reused?

Comment: @javapowered really I don't know. Maybe standard allows some string optimizations in their realisation, like lazy-copying... You'd better ask someon who've read standard =)

Comment: I don't have the latest standard, so things may be different now; the 2003 one states that "the function replaces the string controlled by *this with a string [...] whose first [...] elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string controlled by *this". Reusing the original string may fall under the "as if" rule, but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::copy` algorithm http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/

`std::copy(apples, apples + sz, str.begin() + offset);`

Comment: what OP is trying to do is to add the string without copying, which is not possible.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I think, he was talking about overwriting string's tail. I'll ask him for clarification =)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev i don't want to introduce "intermediate" objects. for example i don't want to convert `char* apples` to intermediate `std::string`. Instead I want to copy string directly to `str` but i need to provide position. I think kassak answered my question.

Comment: If his desire is to append, rather than overwrite, using `std::back_inserter( str )` as the third argument will also do the trick.  There are also a number of member functions: `append`, `insert`, etc.; in this case, the "safest" solution is probably something like `str.replace( offset, std::string::npos, apples )`; this will replace any characters after `offset` with the characters in `apples`, extending or reducing the size of `str` as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Even assign will copy the content of whatever you pass to it. You will not be able to do what you try to. A string holds a pointer to a **continuous** block of characters in the memory. You can not just glue arbitrary things to it.

Comment: i'm ok to `copy`! that's what i want to do. well it seems my question is too simple and i confuse people. I think I just should use `replace`.

Comment: @perreal It depends.  First, the standard makes no guarantees for `std::string`; a conforming implementation can do a reallocation any time a non-const function is called.  If you need guarantees, use `std::vector<char>`.  Second, all of the implementations I've seen _do_ behave more or less like `std::vector<char>`, at least most of the time.  (E.g. g++ may do a reallocation if you use `[]` on a non-const string.  But only the first time; after that, there will be no more reallocation until the capacity is exceeded.)

Comment: @javapowered That's my impression as well.  _If_ `replace` needs to increase the capacity of the string, it will reallocate.  You can avoid this by ensuring sufficient capacity up front.  Also: some implementations (e.g. g++) use reference counting and copy on write.  These _may_ reallocated at odd moments, even when you don't modify the string.  The conditions controlling this are rather complex, and I doubt that it will really be an issue, but if you want guarantees, use `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of using the `std::copy()` algorithm is the best one AFAIK. You could also use plain old C (you understand, it is not actually C, *C style* would be a better name) to achieve the same thing:

```
char* apples = "apples";
std::string str("I like .....");

char * ptr = apples;
while( *ptr != 0 ) {
    str.push_back( *ptr );
    ++ptr;
}
```

As you can see, there is no temporary object created here, but... Does that mean there are no allocations in the process? Indeed they are.

A `std::string` is basically a vector of chars. The string has a `capacity()` method that returns how many extra chars can be appended without triggering another allocation (which can involve a reallocation, thus copying the whole vector). The best you can do in order to avoid allocations is to ensure that the string will have enough space for all characters to insert.

```
char* apples = "apples";
std::string str("I like .....");

str.reserve( str.length() + strlen( apples ) );

char * ptr = apples;
while( *ptr != 0 ) {
    str.push_back( *ptr );
    ++ptr;
}
```

This way you can ensure that there will be one allocation only in the `std::string`: the one triggered with `reserve()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char * apples = "apples";
string something = "I like ....";
    for (int i = 0; i < something.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (something.find('.'))
            something.pop_back();
    }
    something.resize(something.length() + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(apples); i++)
        something.push_back(apples[i]);
cout << something <<endl;
```